# Is it possible to check cell value length in datagridview while typing?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, maxlength

Friends, I'm using a datagridview control in my visual studio 2005 windows application. Here I've 5 columns. Among these 5, 2nd(colIndex 1) and 3rd(colIndex 2) column have text data type and 4th(colIndex 3)and 5th(colIndex 4) have double data type column. Now I've to check the cell value length for colIndex 1 and 2 whether the entered value length is greater than a specific(10 for colIndex 1 and 100 for colIndex 2) value? If so then I've to show corresponding message. Can you suggest in which datagridview event I should check the entered/typed cell value and how to check the value? I've used following code in CellValidating event

```
    string columnName = dgView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;

        if (dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgViewColumn.TAN].Value.ToString().Length > 10)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show(columnName + " must be 10 Digits Long!");
        }
```

But it's showing columnName of next column.
And as I've a feature for the grid that pressing "Enter" key will move the focus to next cell, it's showing error as "Operation did not succeed because the program cannot commit or quit a cell value change."  in CellValidating event. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you know that the `CellValidating` event would be triggered for each cell, so maybe you are seeing the message since it might fail for the length part of the `double` datatype columns.

So you should put a check that you are checking the first and second column respectively and then doing the checks for length.

you can also choose to use `e.FormattedValue` to get the current value in the cell too.

Also you can set the `MaxInputLength` for the Textbox column in the properties too (in case you need it)

Comment: the grid is not a bound type. It's a entry type grid.Then how will I set MaxLength?

Comment: well if you look in properties of the textbox column (in the designer) you would see `MaxInputLength` which you can set to 10 or 100 as you need

Comment: Boss, the type of data to be entered is text type and these checkings are done through code so it's not possible to get textbox column.

Comment: you said you are using `DataGridView` and since you are typing in some text, i assumed they must be the build in `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` unless you have used something else